# Gnuplot 'QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display'

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following simple gnuplot script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
clear
reset
set ...
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'foobaz.png'
plot filename using 2:5:xtic(1) title 'foobar'
```

When I execute on my local machine it executes fast with no warnings. On the other hand, when I execute it in a **remote** machine, although it produces the desired `png` file it takes much more time (around to 10s-20s) and produces the following warnings:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to existing gnuplot_qt. Starting a new one.
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 

Warning: slow font initialization
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

Although, this problem occurred to others as well, I couldn't find a solution in the context of gnuplot. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to do this on a remote machine, and the output was

```
gnuplot_qt: cannot connect to X server 
: cannot connect to X server
```

But there are no errors if the command `set terminal pngcairo` is before all other commands. It's because your (and my) default terminal is `qt`, and the commands `clear` and `reset` are executed in the context of this terminal, which is impossible because remote connection goes without connecting to X server.

Comment: The culprit is only the `clear`. From the docs: "The clear command erases the current screen or output device as specified by set output."